# GetProcAddress returning the correct address with Visual C++ and an incorrect address with g++

Tags: g++, mingw-w64

This is going to sound really strange.  I am using Visual Studio 2017 C++ (native mode) and also, g++ 4.7.1-2 of the MingW toolchain.  Target is Windows 64bit.

Using VS C++, I compile the following trivial program:
`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI* RTLINT64)(ULONGLONG, ULONG, PUNICODE_STRING);

RTLINT64 RtlInt64 = (RTLINT64) nullptr;

int main()
{
  UNICODE_STRING unicodestring    = { 0 };
  WCHAR          localbuffer[256] = { 0 };    // way more than enough

  __int64        value            =   0;

  unicodestring.Length = 0;
  unicodestring.MaximumLength = sizeof(localbuffer);
  unicodestring.Buffer = (PWCH) &localbuffer;

  // get ntdll's module handle 

  HMODULE NtDllModule = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
  if (NtDllModule)
  {
     RtlInt64 = (RTLINT64) GetProcAddress(NtDllModule,
                                          "RtlInt64ToUnicodeString");

     value = 0xFFFFFFFFF;
     RtlInt64 (value, 10, &unicodestring);

     wprintf(L"%s\n", unicodestring.Buffer);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

`
As expected, GetProcAddress returns the address of RtlInt64ToUnicodeString (no surprise there!)

The code below is, with exception of the includes, pretty much a carbon copy of the above.  Yet, somehow, in that version compiled with G++, GetProcAddress returns the address of RtlInterlockedSetBitRun instead of the address of RtlInt64ToUnicodeString (that IS a surprise!).  Here is the code:

```
// GCC  and MingW version

#include <Windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <winternl.h>

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* RTLINT64)(ULONGLONG, ULONG, PUNICODE_STRING);

RTLINT64 RtlInt64 = (RTLINT64) nullptr;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  WCHAR          localbuffer[256] = {0};     // way more than enough
  UNICODE_STRING unicodestring    = {0};

  __int64        value            =   0;

  unicodestring.Length = 0;
  unicodestring.MaximumLength = sizeof(localbuffer);
  unicodestring.Buffer = (PWCH) &localbuffer;

  // get ntdll's module handle 

  HMODULE NtDllModule = LoadLibraryW(L"ntdll.dll");
  if (NtDllModule)
  {
     RtlInt64 = (RTLINT64) GetProcAddress(NtDllModule,
                                     "RtlInt64ToUnicodeString");

     // the above call to GetProcAddress returned the address of 
     // RtlInterlockedSetBitRun instead of the address of the requested function

     // as a result, the statements below don't work.

         value = 0xFFFFFFFFF;
     RtlInt64(value, 10, &unicodestring);

     wprintf(L"%s\n", unicodestring.Buffer);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**my question is:** is there something in the above code that justifies the discrepancy ?

Also note that, I am using G++ with a tool called VisualGDB which integrates the compiler and the debugger into Visual Studio.  Normally things of that kind can cause strange "side effects" but, in this case, it seems rather unlikely for something that has nothing to do with ntdll to be the culprit.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does it crash with the g++ version? Or what's the output?

Comment: it does crash because the parameters to RtlInterlockedSetBitRun are not the same as those of RtlInt64ToUnicodeString.  I had to step through the assembly code to convince myself it wasn't calling RtlInt64ToUnicodeString and it is not.  It is calling RtlInterlockedSetBitRun.    I see it and I still have a hard time believing it.

Comment: It works just fine on my end with g++, so I can't explain what's happening on your end.

Comment: @ssbssa: that tells me that VisualGDB thing that I've been trying is the likely culprit.  I find it surprising but, the fact that it runs fine for you indicates that somehow that thing is responsible for the problem.  It's very strange because, other than that, everything works as expected.  Thank you for taking the time to test it on your end.  I appreciate it.